# Mocking a Celery task call in Python with patch

Tags: python, mocking, celery, celery-task, python-mock

Patching a Celery task call with a mocked return value returns `<Mock name='mock().get()' ...>` instead of the expected `return_value` defined by `mock_task.get.return_value = "value"`. However, the mocked task functions correctly within my unit test.

Here is the unit test where I am patching my Celery task:

```
def test_foo(self):

    mock_task = Mock()
    mock_task.get = Mock(return_value={'success': True})

    print mock_task.get() # outputs {'success': True}

    with patch('app.tasks.my_task.delay', new=mock_task) as mocked_task:
        foo()  # this calls the mocked task with an argument, 'input from foo'
        mock_tasked.assert_called_with('input from foo')  # works
```

And here is the function being tested:

```
def foo():
    print tasks.my_task.delay  # shows a Mock object, as expected
    # now let's call get() on the mocked task:
    task_result = tasks.my_task.delay('input from foo').get()
    print task_result  # => <Mock name='mock().get()' id='122741648'>
    # unexpectedly, this does not return {'success': True}
    if task_result['success']:
        ...
```

The last line raises `TypeError: 'Mock' object has no attribute '__getitem__'`

Why can I call mock_task.get() from within my unit test, but calling it from `foo` returns a `<Mock ...>` instead of the expected return value?

Answer (score 8):

Unfortunately I know  almost nothing about Celery, but it looks like the problem is with mocking.

You have:

```
tasks.my_task.delay('input from foo').get()
```

After `patch('app.tasks.my_task.delay', new=mock_task)` it becomes:

```
mock_task('input from foo').get()
```

Which is not the same as:

```
mock_task.get()
```

You should change your mock creation to:

```
mock_task().get = Mock(return_value={'success': True})
```

New Mock instance is created by default when you access existing Mock attribute or call it. So we can simplify it a little:

```
mock_task().get.return_value = {'success': True}
```